# Owl.carousel can not work after project migrated from Vue-cli 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack, owl-carousel, vue-cli

Originally, the Owl.Carousel work fine when I running it under the Vue-cli2.0 ,but after I migrate the project to Vue-cli 3.0 the console keep occur this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at eval (owl.carousel.js?555f:1718)
at eval (owl.carousel.js?555f:1755)
at Object../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js (chunk-vendors.js:2031)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (main.js:28)
at Module../src/main.js (app.js:2285)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at Object.1 (app.js:2410)
```

And it seems like something went wrong in the **owl.carousel.js** (:1718) which tagged by the dev tool.

```
$.fn.owlCarousel = function(option) { .......
```

At first, I thought that I didn't import the JQuery properly ,but after import the JQuery in the local .Vue file (which carousel used in). It still not working.
Then I found a solution that import the JQuery from the webpack setting. So I add some code in the "**vue.config.js**"

```
    const webpack = require('webpack');

   module.exports = {
     lintOnSave: false,
     configureWebpack: {
       plugins: [
         new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: 'jquery',
           jQuery: 'jquery',
           'windows.jQuery': 'jquery',
         }),
       ],
     },
   };
```

Is it possible Vue-cli 3.0  incompatible for Owl.Carousel or just I import the jQuery wrongly ?
Otherwise, does anyone recommend other carousel plugin which can show multiple items in once and also responsive ?